# Is there a way to change screen resolution for HTML5's fullscreen videos?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, video, webkit

I'm currently developing a media center built upon Webkit + nodeJS (is like a Chrome brower within an desktop application). I want to change the screen refresh rate (HZ) based on the FPS of the video that is currently playing (only in fullscreen), so for example if my screen resolution is 1920x1080@60hz and play a 1080p@24fps video, i want the screen resolution to change to 1920x1080@24hz.

This practice is very common among media centers, just because matching the screen's refresh rate with the video's FPS ensure a more pleasant and smooth playback.

So, my question is simple: Is there a way to do this within JavaScript or HTML5?